# How to Unit test HTML output from node?

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing

This might be a dumb question: I have an `.html` file with one `<script>` (main.js) initially loaded on it, which programmatically add structure on that html file. Also this script adds another  which uses that structure to draw some charts.

Then, I am serving this html with node. Also I am serving those scripts in my server.js like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.write('File not found!');
    } else {
        res.write(data);
    }
    res.end();
  });
});

app.get('/main.js', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/..' + '/main.js'));
});
```

And so...
Everything is working great. User can't have interaction with the page, so everything will remain the same .

Now, I want to develop  some unit tests on that .html (like check elements, values, etc.).
I did a lot of research, but I can't find the answer or some clue to lead me, given this situation.

How should I do it?
Am I structuring things wrongly to accomplish my goal, or not following good practices?